# Insert a number sequence into 3 different tables using 1 oracle table column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table T1 contains column C1 which has values (1,2,3,4....3000). I need to populate these records into 3 Tables T2,T3,T4 in the following form:
Values
T2:1,4,7,10....
T3:2,5,8,11....
T4:3,6,9,12....

How can I write SQL to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) for this:

> ```
> insert all
>   when grp = 0
>   then into t1(id) values(rn)
>   when grp = 1
>   then  into t2(id) values(rn)
>   when grp = 2
>   then  into t3(id) values(rn)
>
> select t.*, mod(rn-1, 3) as grp
> from t
> ```
>
> 9 rows affected

> ```
> select
>   'T1' as src, id
> from t1
>
> union all
>
> select
>   'T2', id
> from t2
>
> union all
>
> select
>   'T3', id
> from t3
> ```
>
> ```
> SRC | ID
> :-- | -:
> T1  |  1
> T1  |  4
> T1  |  7
> T2  |  2
> T2  |  5
> T2  |  8
> T3  |  3
> T3  |  6
> T3  |  9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8d703c506c059f1da2c2a955a3ecf613)*